# HTML get option value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <select id="ChangeViewId" onChange="changeView(this)"></select>

   function setView() {
 ..................... 
   var innerCode = '';
    for(i=0; i<viewList.length; i++) {                      
      innerCode += "<option value="+viewList[i]+">"+viewList[i]+"</option>";
     }
        document.getElementById("ChangeViewId").innerHTML=innerCode;
    }

function changeView(view)
    {       
        alert(document.getElementById('ChangeViewId').value);
    }
```

The values are C, Cpp,Java program. when i select Java program only Java is displaying i want Complete value Java program. I have tried with both  onSelect and onClick
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script generates this HTML:

```
<option value=Java program>Java program</option>
```

That is, an option tag that has value "Java" and a property "program". You need to add quotes around the value:

```
innerCode += '<option value="'+viewList[i]+'">'+viewList[i]+"</option>";
```

Comment: It is generally good practice to encase your Javascript strings with single quotes ' so that you can write html markup more easily.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
function setView() 
{
   var innerCode = '';
   for(i=0; i< viewList.length; i++) 
   {                      
      innerCode += '<option value="'+viewList[i]+'">' + viewList[i] + '</option>';
   }

   document.getElementById("ChangeViewId").innerHTML=innerCode;
}

function changeView(view)
{       
    var objSel = document.getElementById('ChangeViewId');
    alert(objSel.options[objSel.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Comment: I changed the way you got alerted as you didn't specify HTML version this should work 3.2 upwards